# Differentiating a scalar function $f := z \, \beta^T \left({\Sigma}+zI\right)^{-1} \beta$ w.r.t. $z$.

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-calculus

I have a function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$ f(z) := z \, \beta^T \left({\Sigma}+zI\right)^{-1} \beta $$

and I want to find its derivative with respect to $z$. I tried making use of

[image]

and

[image]

in a chain rule, but it doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Of course you will also need a product rule: $\partial (fg) = f (\partial g) + (\partial f) g.$

Comment: $$((\Sigma+zI)(\Sigma+zI)^{-1})'=I(\Sigma+zI)^{-1}+(\Sigma+zI)((\Sigma+zI)^{-1})'=I'=0$$

gives

$$((\Sigma+zI)^{-1})'=-((\Sigma+zI)^{-1})^2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good to come back to entries themselves. Here is how.

Let us assume that $\Sigma$ is diagonalizable under the form:

$$\Sigma = P \Lambda P^{-1}$$

with $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_k)$. We can transform:

$$f(z)=z\beta^T\left({\Sigma}+zI\right)^{-1}\beta$$

into:

$$f(z)=z\beta^T\left(P \Lambda P^{-1}+zPP^{-1}\right)^{-1}\beta$$

$$f(z)=z\beta^T\left(P(\Lambda +zI)P^{-1}\right)^{-1}\beta$$

$$f(z)=z\underbrace{\beta^TP}_{U^T}(\Lambda +zI)^{-1}\underbrace{P^{-1}\beta}_V$$

As $\Lambda +zI$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_k+z$, is we denote by $u_k$ and $v_k$ the entries of $U$ and $V$, we get:

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{u_kv_kz}{\lambda_k+z}$$

whose derivative is :

$$f'(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{u_kv_k\lambda_k}{(\lambda_k+z)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_k \lambda_k \dfrac{1}{(\lambda_k+z)^2} v_k$$

Now it remains to do the journey back to a matricial expression...

$$f'(z)=\underbrace{(\beta^TP)}_{U^T} \Lambda (\Lambda +zI)^{-2}\underbrace{(P^{-1}\beta)}_V$$

$$f'(z)=\beta^T\underbrace{(P \Lambda P^{-1})}_{\Sigma} \underbrace{(P(\Lambda +zI)^{-2}P^{-1})}_{(\Sigma + zI)^{-2} }\beta$$

i.e.,

$$f'(z)=\beta^T\Sigma \left({\Sigma}+zI\right)^{-2}\beta$$

or equivalently:

$$f'(z)=\beta^T \left({\Sigma}+zI\right)^{-2} \Sigma\beta$$

**Remarks:**

1. If $\Sigma$ is not diagonalizable, our reasoning is still valid because a non diagonalizable matrix can always be considered as the limit of a sequence of diagonalizable matrices.
2. If $\Sigma$ is symmetric (which is likely), $P^{-1}=P^T$ implying that $U=V$.

Comment: Any reference that any matrix is the limit of diagonalisable matrices?

Comment: @Will M. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/199284) is one by using triangularizations.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\l{\big(}
\def\r{\big)}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}
$For
typing convenience, define the matrix
$$\eqalign{
A = (\Sigma+zI) \quad\implies\quad \c{dA = I\,dz} \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij} Y_{ij}\;=\;{\rm Tr}(X^TY) \\
X:X &= \big\|X\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
Write the function using the above notation, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \beta\beta^T:A^{-1}z \\
df &= \beta\beta^T:\l A^{-1}\,dz + z\;\c{dA^{-1}}\r \\
 &= \beta\beta^T:\l A^{-1}\,dz \c{-} z\;\c{A^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1}}\r \\
 &= \beta\beta^T:\l A - zI\r A^{-2}dz \\
 &= \beta\beta^T:\Sigma A^{-2}dz \\
\grad{f}{z} &= \beta\beta^T:\Sigma A^{-2}
 \quad=\; \beta^T\Sigma A^{-2}\beta \\
}$$
where the part in $\c{\rm red}$ makes use of the second of your identities.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(z) = z\beta^\intercal$ and $v(z) = (\Sigma + zI)^{-1} \beta.$ Then,
$$
\partial_z (uv) = (\partial_z u) v(z) + u \partial_z v(z).
$$
In the equation above, all derivatives are matrix representation, so $\partial_zu = \beta^\intercal.$ Using $\partial_x (A(x) \beta) = (\partial_x A) \beta,$ and your formula for the inverse, we see
$$
\partial_z v = -(\Sigma + zI)^{-1} \partial_z (\Sigma + zI) (\Sigma + zI)^{-1} \beta = -(\Sigma + zI)^{-2} \beta.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\partial_z(uv) = \beta^\intercal(\Sigma + zI)^{-1}\beta - z\beta^\intercal(\Sigma + zI)^{-2} \beta.
$$

**Note.** If you write $\Sigma = P \Lambda P^{-1}$ as the other answer does, you will find that this result and the other one match. Now, when the matrix is non-diagonalisable, apparently, one can do a diagonalisation approximation, but even then one still needs to prove that one can change the limit and the derivative for you are writing $f(z) = \lim\limits_n f_n(z)$ with the matrices in $f_n$ diagonalisable.